# Upserting data from table to database?

Tags: javascript, http, post, vue.js, put

I've got a time-tracking sheet web-app where each row represents a user in the database and each column has an input field where the user will put in their amount of hours worked for that specific day. 
A fiddle to show you what it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/L5u1fc0a/138/

Basically, how can I make sure that I only send new data to the database. I wish to (obviously) display current values in the table, and I'm fetching that data and storing it in a Vue `v-model` (see `worklogs` in the fiddle) - this data in `worklogs` is what populates the table. My issue is that I don't know how to handle additional hours. If a user adds another hour at a specific date and hits "Update" (in the fiddle, "Save"), it'll send the entire `worklogs` data value which holds all current values + the new one, so if someone were to add only one input, it'll still send everything in the `worklogs`object. In the fiddle, if you enter a new value somewhere and hit the "Save" button, you can see my array `updateData`populating all existing values as well - how can I only send the newly updated values to the database?

Comment: Include a "dirty" flag with your data, so you know what has changed. Set it to false for all the items when they are saved. Set it to true every time an update is made.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Not sure what that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really figure out what's updated if you're changing the data as you go. You need to keep them separate while you're working, and then just save the updateData. So I renamed your `worklogs` to `saved`, and made `updateData` an object that will hold entries of exactly the same type as `saved` does.

I made a computed that merges `saved` and `updateData`, and used that for the bound `value`. You can't really use `v-model` here because you can't write individual elements back to a computed dictionary. But you don't need to. On change, you update `updateData` and the `value` stays consistent.

(Side note: if you made each input a component, you could use `v-model`, but there would still be all the plumbing to handle in the parent.)

The `save` function does whatever back-end calls it does, updates `saved`, and empties `updateData`.

```js
/* app instance */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
     const currentDate = new Date();
     return {
      saved: {
        "1,2018-11-01": "8", 
        "1,2018-11-02": "8",
        "2,2018-11-03": "10",
        "2,2018-11-04": "10"
    },
      updateData: {},
      users: [
          {id: 1, firstName: 'Jay', lastName: 'Carter', email: 'jayz@rocafella.com'},
          {id: 2, firstName: 'Day', lastName: 'Darter', email: 'dayz@rocafella.com'}
        ],
        secondHalf: false,
        selectedYear: currentDate.getFullYear(),
        selectedMonth: currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
        
    };
  },
  methods: {
    prevPeriod() {
      if (!this.secondHalf) {
        this.selectedMonth -= 1;
        this.secondHalf = !this.secondHalf;
      } else {
        this.secondHalf = !this.secondHalf;
      }
      if (this.selectedMonth < 1) {
        this.selectedYear -= 1;
        this.selectedMonth = 12;
      }
    },
    nextPeriod() {
      if (this.secondHalf) {
        this.selectedMonth += 1;
        this.secondHalf = !this.secondHalf;
      } else {
        this.secondHalf = !this.secondHalf;
      }
      if (this.selectedMonth > 12) {
        this.selectYear += 1;
        this.selectedMonth = 1;
      }
    },
    getMonth(date) {
      const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
      return months[date.getMonth()];
    },
    getWeekDay(date) {
      const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
     return days[date.getDay()];
    },
    setUpdateData(userId, day, event) {
      const key = this.dataKey(userId, day);
      const value = event.target.value;
      
      if (this.saved[key] !== value) {
       this.$set(this.updateData, key, value);
      } else {
       this.$delete(this.updateData, key);
      }
    },
    save() {
   // Presumably, this would go somewhere that would refresh saved, but
      // the ultimate effect is just to copy the updateData into saved and
      // empty updateData
   Object.assign(this.saved, this.updateData);
      this.updateData = {};
  },
    dataKey(userId, day) {
     return `${userId},${this.convertDateString(day)}`;
    },
    convertDateString(date) {
      let isoWithTimezone = new Date(
        date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000
      ).toISOString();
      return isoWithTimezone.split("T")[0];
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
   allData() {
     return Object.assign({}, this.saved, this.updateData);
    },
    getDates() {
      const year = this.selectedYear;
      const month = this.selectedMonth;
      
      let currentDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
      const dates = [];
      
      while (currentDate.getMonth() == month - 1) {
        dates.push(currentDate);
        currentDate = new Date(
         currentDate.getFullYear(),
          currentDate.getMonth(),
         currentDate.getDate() + 1
        );
      }
      
      if (this.secondHalf) {
        return dates.slice(15);
      } else {
        return dates.slice(0, 15);
   }
    },
  }
})
```

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p>{{this.selectedYear}} - {{this.selectedMonth}}</p>
    <div>
      <button @click="prevPeriod"> ‹‹ </button>
      <button @click="nextPeriod"> ›› </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table id="conTab">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td v-for="(date, key) in getDates" :key="key" style="font-size: 80%;"> {{getWeekDay(date)}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-top-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px"></td>
          <td v-for="(date, key) in getDates" :key="key" style="font-size: 80%;"> {{getMonth(date)}} {{date.getDate()}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(user, i) in users" :key="user.id">
            <td>
              {{user.firstName}}
            </td>
            <td v-for="(day, key) in getDates" :key="key">
              <input type="number" style="width: 35px;" :value="allData[dataKey(user.id, day)]" @change="setUpdateData(user.id, day, $event)">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div><button @click="save">SAVE</button></div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{$data}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your elaborate comment, thanks a lot. Just glancing at my way of doing this, would you say I could have done something way easier? My endgoal is to have a timesheet that looks like an Excel grid pretty much..

Comment: A lot of the work was with date. I don't know if maybe a library like moment.js would have simplified that. Other than that, there's not a whole lot that has room to get way easier.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your code, do you suggest I send the data from `updateData` to my backend? Because if I were to save everything from `updateData` to `saved` and then post the `saved` object to the backend, nothing hasn't really changed - `saved`will still all hold all values, from before and the newly updated ones

Comment: You send `updateData` to your backend. Putting it into `saved` is just to _reflect_ the fact that it is now saved data.

Comment: Hey Roy, can I just ask you about the whole logic with `:value` and `@change` - not entirely sure I grasp how that all works.
The `@change` value stores the input value and the user.id + date but I'm not sure what the `if (this.saved[key] !== value)` does.

Comment: Compares the new value to the value that is already saved. If they're the same, it removes it from the update list, because it doesn't need to be saved.

Comment: If I just try to console.log `this.saved[key]`after typing in some value I'll always get undefined. The solution works fine - just trying to understand it.
Also, the `$set`, `$delete` and `$event` variables - are they built-in Vue values? Where "do they go"?

Comment: They are [instance methods](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Data) in Vue.

Comment: Any idea how I can separate existing values and new values? I wish to send the existing values to an axios `put` function to update those values and any new ones to an axios `post` function

Comment: Existing values are ones where `key in this.saved`.

Comment: I've got an upsert function that sends the data to my backend. If I send the data the way you helped me configure, it'll always post that data. For all existing logged hours there's an "hour_id" (incremental id for each new row that is inserted). 

I can send the response like this: https://imgur.com/a/g2YAfx3
(can't do multi-line code in comments)


The second item you see in the array will insert a new row and the first item will update an existing row since I provide an existing id. I somehow need to have the `this.saved` function store the existing hour id. Does that make sense?

Comment: You just need to have a `newData` in addition to `updateData`. When a change comes in, you test whether the key is in saved data; if not, the entry goes in `newData`. Otherwise, in `updateData` (or delete from updateData if the value is the same as saved)

Comment: Okay, lemme try it out, thanks. Am I setting myself up for spaghetti code doing it this way? This is my first real project but I'd still like to get the fundamentals done correctly.

Comment: Any chance I can pm you / chat on discord?

Comment: I'm not on discord. You can ask a new question.

Comment: I added some changes in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h64wafkp/6/ I'm also now using a library to make the date handling a bit easier. Essentially, what you'll see in `savedHours` is userid, date, hourid and duration. Not sure why the input fields are blank on load after I added the hour id  to the key in the object (the last digit there which represents the hour id) Also, if you try to enter a value in one of the input fields, you'll see newHours being populated - not sure how to get the hour id in here if it exists

Comment: Essentially, what I don't understand is why my :value won't bind the correct values if I add another argument to the function. I'm adding the hour id in the object deconstruction as such: 
`const { user_id, date, duration} = item;` and it's correctly reflected in my `savedHours` but it won't show in the value cells even after adding something like 
`:value="allData[dataKey(user.id, day, user.hours.id)]"`

Comment: You have a typo: `dayh` in `:value="allData[dataKey(user.id, dayh)]"` should be `day`

Comment: I fixed that typo but it's still not displaying anything. Check my latest fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/h64wafkp/6/)

I don't understand why values in `savedHours` won't be displayed in the grid if I add another key to the object, what am I missing here

Comment: The keys in savedData don't match the keys in updateData because of the hour_id. I'm not sure how you want to work that out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185000/discussion-between-erikvm-and-roy-j).